# How to change button labels in alertify - v0.3.11

Tags: javascript, alertify

How to change button labels in alertify - v0.3.11

I am using the below code

```
alertify.confirm("Are you sure you want to cancel this order?", function (e) {
          if (e) {

              document.forms.SFOrder.action=<cfoutput>'#self#=#xfa.cancelOrder#'</cfoutput>;
              document.forms.SFOrder.submit();
              return true;

          } else {
            return false;
          }
      }).setting('labels',{'ok':'Accept', 'cancel': 'Decline'});
```

But it is giving below error

Uncaught TypeError: alertify.confirm(...).setting is not a function

Answer (score 1):

```
alertify.okBtn("Accept").cancelBtn("Decline").confirm("Are you sure you want to cancel this order?", function (e) {
    if (e) {
        document.forms.SFOrder.action=<cfoutput>'#self#=#xfa.cancelOrder#'</cfoutput>;
        document.forms.SFOrder.submit();
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my example:

```js
function confirmar(mje, x) {
  var rta = 0;
  var confirm = alertify.confirm('<img src="../imagenes/charleston bar login.png" width="450" />', '<h1>' + mje + '</h1>', null, null).set('labels', {
    ok: 'Confirmar',
    cancel: 'Cancelar'
  });


  //callbak al pulsar botón positivo
  confirm.set('onok', function() {
    eval(x);

  });
  //callbak al pulsar botón negativo
  confirm.set('oncancel', function() {

  });
}
```

Comment: Answer would be improved by adding some context on the error in the original code and how your solution addresses it